# Is there a logic more expressive than Default Logic?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity

According to [On the intertranslatability of non‐monotonic logics](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1018915113814), DL (default logic),  SAEL (strong autoepistemic logic) and PL (priority logic) have the same expressive power in the following polynomial time hierarchy (PH):

[image]

(NDL (normal default logic), 
AEL (autoepistemic logic), 
PDL (prerequisite-free default logic), 
WDL (weak default logic), 
PNDL (prerequisite-free and normal default logic), 
CIRC (parallel circumscription),
CL (classical propositional logic)).

My question is: Is there a logic more expressive than Default Logic?